# Is it more efficient to use sys or fileinput library to read from standard input in python?

Tags: python, file, input

I think the question is self explanatory.
If I want to execute a program that takes an input from a file, will it execute faster if I import and use sys library rather than fileinput or there will be no difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading and writing to a disk is thousands of times slower than accessing memory (and that's much slower than accessing the CPU cache or just executing instructions), so it's unlikely that there would be a significant difference unless the library is amazingly inefficient. It's also unlikely that this would be the bottleneck if your program, but [you should profile it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) if you're still concerned.